# fmod Sound.setMusicSpeed returning unsupported format error

Tags: c#, c++, mp3, wav, fmod

whenever I try using Sound.getMusicSpeed() or Sound.setMusicSpeed, the returned result is a "Unsupported file or audio format". 
I tried with a .mp3, a .ogg and a .wav, but they all return the same error. I tried both in C++ and wit the C# wrapper.
Is there anything specific I should know about get/setMusicSpeed()? The documentation on this function is pretty straight forward. Thanks!

Comment: the only thing I can find about it is "00246         // For MOD/S3M/XM/IT/MID sequenced formats only." from http://zwischenwelt.org/~hagish/irisdocs/trunk/doc/api_cpp/html/fmod_8hpp-source.html

Comment: I guess that explains it. After a quick google search you find that mp3, ogg and wav are NOT sequenced format. Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it thx! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of seaching on the internet revealed this link

http://zwischenwelt.org/~hagish/irisdocs/trunk/doc/api_cpp/html/fmod_8hpp-source.html

which further searching leads me to this comment

`"00246 // For MOD/S3M/XM/IT/MID sequenced formats only."`

a bit more googling leads to the discovery that mp3, ogg, and wav are NOT such sequenced formats.

Comment: Google Foo is an oft underestimated skill.  Being able to structure what you are looking for, in a way the search engine can understand, to give you actual results instead of having to dig through page after page of drivel and garbage!!  But yes, sometimes its rather simple to look it up online.  Remember people, the internet knows everything, eventually.